# Как объектам списка присвоить значения?

Tags: python

есть список

```
a = ['красный', 'синий']
```

надо присвоить к ним два значения, к примеру `красный` - 1 и 0.
`синий` -  2 и 3

Comment: Не понятно, что вы хотите сделать. Может объясните, как вы хотите использовать потом это все.

Comment: Кроме словарей можно ещё просто в кортежи данные объединить: `a = [('красный', 0, 1), ('синий', 2, 3)]`, а можно и вообще классы начать писать и полям класса что-нибудь присваивать.

Answer (score 3):

> Можно ли объектам списка присвоить значения?

В общем случае нет. Значение не присваивается объектам. По сути объект — это и есть значение. Вы используете неправильную терминологию.

Вы можете присвоить значение какой-либо переменной. Можете добавить его в список. А можете присвоить ключу словаря.

Думаю, именно [словарь](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) вы и ищите:

```py
a = {'красный': [1, 0], 'синий': [2, 3]}
print(a['красный'])
```

stdout:

```py
[1, 0]
```

---

Если порядок значений не важен, и они не повторяются, то можете воспользоваться [множествами](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```py
a = {'красный': {1, 0}, 'синий': {2, 3}}
```